# Error converting format from object to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a data type object to a float in Pandas, but I cannot fix this error.

To simplify the explanation and ensure clear understanding, I will show the whole picture using a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'id': ['EC','4E','E1','F8','4E'],
'item_date': [20210401, 20210401, 20210401, 20210401, 20210401],
'quantity tons': [54.15113862, 768.0248392, 386.1279489, 202.4110654, 'e'],
'customer': [30156308, 30202938, 30153963, 30349574, 30211560],
'country': [28, 25, 30, 32, 28],
'status': ['Won', 'Won', 'Won', 'Won', 'Won']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried to convert the column to `float` like this:

```
df["quantity tons"] = df["quantity tons"].astype(float)
```

But it shows an error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Overdose AI\part_a.ipynb Cell 4 in 1
----> 1 df["quantity tons"] = df["quantity tons"].astype(float)

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6245, in NDFrame.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   6238     results = [
   6239         self.iloc[:, i].astype(dtype, copy=copy)
   6240         for i in range(len(self.columns))
   6241     ]
   6243 else:
   6244     # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 6245     new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   6246     return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   6248 # GH 33113: handle empty frame or series

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:446, in BaseBlockManager.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    445 def astype(self: T, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise") -> T:
--> 446     return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:348, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    346         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    347     else:
--> 348         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    349 except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
...
    169     # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 170     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    172 return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'e'
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example not 19Mb of data to download.

Comment: It looks like your input data is bad: there's a string where a number should be.

Comment: It's unclear if you have a question, or whether this is just a problem statement. If a question: what solution would you like? You can the input data, or try and handle bad conversions. For the latter: there is quite a bit to find on the internet about conversions which turn bad input into e.g. NaNs, or mark such cells with a mask.

Comment: You can try `pd.to_numeric`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is a string "e" in 'quantity tons' column (line 173088) in the file you provided.

To avoid this issue, I would suggest to check whether a column has any strings before changing its `dtype`. You can use the following code:

```
df[df['quantity tons'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

The output will show you only the rows where 'quantity tons' column contains strings.

Comment: @rashid np :) if it solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer

Comment: srry I am new here